# bash: swapping matching numbers, with usernames contained in a second file

Tags: bash

i want to replace the last number of each line in "file 1", with the matching username from "file 2", to get the posted result.

file 1:

> 28/02/13 46.149002 **259**
>   22/03/13 68.234001 **404**
>   14/03/16 69.835007 **66**
>   29/01/14 87.083008 **540**
>   14/03/16 106.516006 **874**
>   14/03/16 201.552002 **260**
>   03/12/12 207.521011 **278**
>   18/08/16 234.778015 **1002**

file 2:

> user5 **874**
>   user2 **404**
>   user8 **1002**
>   user4 **540**
>   user1 **259**
>   user6 **260**
>   user7 **278**
>   user3 **66**

this is only a part of "file 2". the file actually contains much more users.

result:

> 28/02/13 46.149002 user1
>   22/03/13 68.234001 user2
>   14/03/16 69.835007 user3
>   29/01/14 87.083008 user4
>   14/03/16 106.516006 user5
>   14/03/16 201.552002 user6
>   03/12/12 207.521011 user7
>   18/08/16 234.778015 user8

Comment: -1. You may get a complete solution here but in general we're not a script writing service. The question doesn't show your research effort *at all*. What have you tried so far? E.g.: "I think it can be done with (name the tool) and (name another tool). I've found this solution (give link) but I'm having trouble modifying it to my needs. My script so far is (paste code)." You don't have to be that good but show us *you* have done something more than posting this question here and sitting tight. Leave me a comment when you improve ([edit]) your question and I will revoke my downvote.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too specific to be useful to the broader community.

Answer (score 2):

I assume your files have this strict format where spaces only separate columns (there is no space inside any username etc.). Then this should work (at least on Linux, my testbed is Kubuntu):

```
while read date value number ; do printf "%s %s %s\n" "$date" "$value" "$(grep " $number" file2 | head -n 1 | cut -f 1 -d " ")" ; done <file1
```

Some explanation:

1. The command reads from `file1` (`… <file1`).
2. As long as it can read a line (`while read …`) …
3. … it prints it (`printf …`) with the third field replaced by …
4. … the effect (`$( … )`) of …

   1. … searching for a line containing the given number inside `file2` (`grep …`, note the leading space: `" $number"`) …
   2. … where only the first match is taken (`head …`, just in case), …
   3. … and then only the first column is left (`cut …`).